# Multiple xml files in testng are not running jdbc connection in a new file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jdbc

Single "testng.xml" is working fine with jdbc connection. But when i am running two xml files in the master xml file, the "testng2.xml" which is newly created file is somehow not picking jdbc connection and shows this error: "Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path"
I believe a project picks sqljdbc_auth file path from same location and all of my xml are obviously under same project. Kindly Assist.

The master xml has following script:

```
<suite name="allSuites">
 <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="testng.xml" />
    <suite-file path="testng2.xml" />
 </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added .dll path for the all three xml files under argument tab of Debug configurations and it solved the issue.